# Rewrite пути в nginx через ingress

Tags: nginx, devops, kubernetes

Мне надо настроить мой ингресс так, чтобы по пути /(какая-то строка)/something запрос проксировался на путь /something в сервисе.

Не понял до конца как работает проброс настроек проксирования в `nginx` через `ingress`. Попробовал такой вариант, но не работает:

```yml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: arch.homework
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)/(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
```